# temporary table creation not working in jasperserver(cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction)

Tags: postgresql, jasperserver

I have a function in `postgres` with temporary table.

```
create or replace function sp_test_function()
returns table (id integer,enqu_id integer) as
$BODY$
BEGIN

create temporary table temp_table(
id serial,
enquiry_id integer

) on commit drop;

insert into temp_table(enquiry_id) select enquiry_id  from sales_enquiry;

return query select t.id,enquiry_id from temp_table t;

END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

I have a report in `jasper` and using above function for fetch data. The problem when i run the report from server getting this error `cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction`. I tried `SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE`

```
$BODY$
BEGIN
 SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE
create temporary table temp_table(
id serial,
enquiry_id integer

) on commit drop
```

But got another error `transaction read-write mode must be set before any query`. How to set transaction in postgres function?

Comment: Problem is not within postgresql function, but rather jasper starting transaction in read-only mode, you cant start readwrite transaction within read only one, i might be mistaken

Comment: How to solve this issue?

Comment: have you read http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-remove-readonly-flag-jdbc-and-jndi-data-sources-jasperreports-server    or https://forum.reportserver.net/viewtopic.php?id=549

Comment: Yes thanx dude. Finally i found the answer

Comment: can you post an actual answer which worked for you and close the question?

Comment: k.. check the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer.

Step 1: Open the `context.xml` file (`C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\META-INF\context.xml`)

Add the below code in that file(i am using `postgresql` db)

```
<Resource name="jdbc/your_db_name" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="db_username" password="db_password" 
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ur_db_name?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true"            factory="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSBasicDataSourceFactory"/>
```

Step:2 Open `web.xml` (`C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\web.xml`)

Add the below code

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>some_description</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/ur_db_name</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

Step 3: Restart your `jasperserver`

Step 4: Login to `jasper server` and add `new datasource`. From the Drop down list select `JNDI Data Source` instead of `JDBC Data Source`.

In the text box field `Service Name (required):` type `jdbc/ur_db_name` . And Click `Test Connection` You get a popup message on top `Connection Passed`. That's it Now you can use this `datasource` in reports. Hope this will help.